# Html Encoding Texts in Razor Views

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Texts and/or markups are rendered to output as-is without any html-encoding as we already expect.

For the following, the plain text with markup must be html-encoded.(We don't care about the code output here.)

```
@{ var theVar = "xyz"; }
some text & other text >>@theVar
```

So, the html in the output;

> `some text & other text >>xx`

So, when we want to write some static text that needs to be html-encoded we have to use constructs like;

```
@{ var theVar = "xyz"; }
@("some text & other text >>")@theVar
```

to get the following html in the output;

> `some text &amp; other text &gt;&gt;xyz`

and for clarity when viewed in browser;

> some text & other text >>xyz

So, is there a simple way of doing this? Some shortcut to html encode texts instead of using @("...") for each text which will start to look nasty when there are multiples of them.
What would be the best practice? How do you do this?

Comment: have you tried @Html.Raw（）

Comment: @Ji_in_coding: *"Returns markup that is not HTML encoded."* That sounds like the opposite of what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @RichardDeeming my bad there. wasn't paying too much attention, but  again mvc razor automatically html encode all strings by default; assign the string to a ViewBag variable and use it directly in the cshtml.  Edit, with that i am assuming he has assembled everything the controller. I prepare all contents outside the view

Comment: @Ji_in_coding: I think the question relates to the literal text in the HTML markup, not the string variables. I don't think there's an easy way to encode that automatically - Razor expects your literal text to already be valid HTML.

Comment: Not sure about what you mean about shortcut, since 5 chars are not that much. If you would like better formatted text, maybe you can try: `@helper Encode(Func<object, HelperResult> template)
{
    @Html.Encode(template.Invoke(null))
}`
end call this via `@Encode(@<text>some text & other text >>@theVar</text>)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it is not a big concern when we specify utf-8 encoding for the document. It is not required to html encode characters as entity references except special(<, >, &, ", ') characters when utf-8 encoding used for the document.
Even using & by itself is not wrong for lenient browsers but there would be ambigous cases to consider like volt&amp. So, it would be better to html encode all of these special characters.

Check the W3 Consortium articles "When to use escapes" section;
http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#use